# Jora name with Dots

Tags: json, jora

I am using the Chrome plugin JsonDiscovery that use JORA to Query in JSON and make JSON query. But know when I consult the MS DevOps API that return the fields with dots in the name I coldnt make the query because JORA understand the dot like to get the next field in the hierarchic.

```
    {
        Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea: "Business",
        Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort: 40,
        Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate: "2021-01-11T03:00:00Z",
    }
```

Dows Someone know how I can make the query with those dots in the name ?

Answer (score 0):

When a property has forbidden chars for an identifier, you should use the same approach as in JavaScript, i.e. `$['Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea']`.

For Jora `foo['bar']` is the same as `foo.bar`. However, in first case you can use any chars for a property name, but the second one is faster to type and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

After many times debugging the Jora, I found the `pick` method.

```
..pick("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea")
```